# Finding the index of the quotient group of $\mathbb{Q}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

Consider the subgroup $V$ of $\mathbb{Q}^2$, generated by
$$v_1=\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}\right),v_2=\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5}\right),$$
in other words $V=\{av_1+bv_2:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Let $U$ be the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ of $\mathbb{Q}^2$. What is the index of $U$ in $V$ in other words, what is the cardinality of the quotient group $\frac{V}{U}$?

Clearly  $(1,0)\in V$ and $(0,2)\in V$. What to do next?

Comment: @ThePhoenix See my argument below, it is finite for certain.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez The quotient is not a vector space.  I mean, we could interpret this problem as a quotient of two $\mathbb{Z}$-modules but that does not really support the comment you made.  $V$ is a countable set of points in $\mathbb{Q}^2$, and by observing that $6 v_1 = 0, 20 v_2 = 0$ you could quickly see that $V/U$ is a finite set.  Whereas, clearly $[v_1] \neq [2 v_1]$ which would imply that $V/U$ has at least 3 elements, which contradicts both the claims you made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Check that
$$
a=3v_1-5v_2=\left(\frac{1}{4},0\right)
$$
and
$$
b=-v_1+2v_2=\left(0,\frac{1}{15}\right).
$$
Prove that $V=\langle a,b\rangle$ and $U<V$.

The rest is hopefully clear.

Comment: How have  you guessed that exactly this two elements generate $V?$

Comment: No it's easy to guess. Your hint is good.